# Как автоматически вставить id в код ссылки?

Tags: php

Ситуация такая: На странице написанной на php отображается ссылка например http://usd-rabota.com/?id=46118 а мне необходимо что бы id автоматически подставлялось на страницах html например так http://holdingsilver.com?referal=46118. Т.е. перенаправляется на другой сайт, но id сохраняется с первой ссылки. Помогите пожалуйста, я полный профан, но очень хочется понять как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, то если вы переходите по ссылке http://usd-rabota.com/?id=46118, то на стороне, куда вы переходите вы перехватываете GET запрос с переменной id и её значением 46118 и формируете ссылку.

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
echo "<a href='http://holdingsilver.com?referal=".$id."'>";
```

так же можно использовать механизм php сессий, если данных много

Comment: нет я не перехожу по ссылке.Она вставляется в php документ из строки браузера. Смысл такой человек зарегистрировался в партнерской программе и хочет рекламировать какой либо продукт для этого я ему предоставляю свой сайт где в строке браузера к адресу сайта он добавляет свой партнерский id. Далее он со строки браузера отражается в php документе. В следующем шаге его id  должно автоматически подставится к ссылкам на страницах сайта. В этом случае множество партнеров с разными id смогут рекламировать товар с одного сайта и не будут заморачиваться с написанием сайтов каждый под себя.

Comment: Извиняюсь, все как-то размыто в описании. Но смысл остается тот же. Параметр id из адресной строки нужно перехватывать методом, который я описывал выше

Comment: Из адресной строки я уже вставила ссылку в php документ вот таким способом:
    <?php
    @session_start();
     
    if(isset($_GET["ref_id"]) AND is_numeric($_GET["ref_id"])) {
            $_SESSION["ref_id"] = $_GET["ref_id"];
    }
     
    if(isset($_SESSION["ref_id"])) {
            echo("ID партнера:" . $_SESSION["ref_id"]);
    }
    else {
            echo("Партнер отсутствует.");
    }
    ?>
Далее нужно что бы id подставился на всех страницах сайта где есть ссылка для регистрации http://holdingsilver.com?referal=46118

Comment: я, конечно, далеко не знаток php. Но почему у вас из GET берется с ключом ref_id, а не id. И вам же в ответе показали как подставить в ссылки

Comment: Суть вопроса заключается в том как из php вставить в html, а не как из строки браузера вставить в php. У меня весь сайт написан в html.

Comment: PHP "собирает" страницу, HTML - размечает ее. Иными словами при помощи PHP генерируется HTML-страница. Вы взяли из строки браузера ID - вставляйте его в свои страницы в нужных местах. Как это сделать, показал @Anovoselof. Или же можно так: 

    <a href='http://holdingsilver.com?referal=<?php echo $id; ?>'>текст ссылки</a>